# Getting exception while push navigation controller - iOS

Tags: ios, swift5

Why I am getting an exception while navigating. I am a beginner for the iOS development. I am navigating once the user has log in. I have used following code. I don't understand what I am missing.

I got the following exeption at last line -

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
   let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "taskListController") as! TaskListController
     self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

Please let me know my mistake.[image]

Comment: can you give us the exception here you have several places where you can have nil

Comment: Have you embedded the login view controller in a navigation controller?

Comment: you debug with brakpoint where is the nil first option secondVoewControllr second one navigationController

Comment: I have mentioned exception line in question. Other than that what do you want exactly? @m1sh0

Comment: You have two force unwrappings (!) they're asking which code line has the exception, you've provided 3 lines. Is it this line that throws the exceptions `let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "taskListController") as! TaskListController` or is it `self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)`. If it's the second one it would appear you don't have a navigation controller. If it's the first one then it looks like your "main" storyboard doesn't have the viewController in it

Comment: At this line i found exception -  self.navigationController!.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

Comment: How to add navigation controller programmatically or through storyboard?

Comment: In storyboard select your root viewcontroller and choose "editor -> embed in -> navigationcontroller"

Comment: I added this but still the issue is same.  @TommyBs

Answer (score 0):

You must add a navigation controller first before you push a VC

## Navigation controller using code

```
func goToMyVC(){
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let mainView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourVC") as? yourVC
        {
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let nav1 = UINavigationController()
            nav1.isNavigationBarHidden = true //Show or hide nav bar
            nav1.viewControllers = [mainView]
            self.window!.switchRootViewController(nav1)
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } }
```

In your viewcontroller call this function,

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.goToMyVC()
```

## Navigation controller from story

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "controller") as? controller

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Comment: How to add that?

Comment: @TejasRatunawar - I have edited the answer is that clear for you?

Comment: Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'window'

Comment: suddenly xcode simulator shows black screen while launching app @kannan T

Comment: Try by replacing my function with this==============>



func goToMyVC() 
{
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let mainView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourVC") as? yourVC
        {
            self.window?.rootViewController?.pushViewController(mainView, animated: true)
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } 
}

Comment: Okay. Wait a moment.

Comment: Navigation controller using code will work but animation for it is not working. @kannan T

Answer (score 0):

Try the blow codes,

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "taskListController") as? TaskListController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController!, animated: true)
```

and make sure that you embedded the login view controller in a navigation controller